# WPF MVVM Data Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Im trying to implement the MVVM Pattern i just want to have a TextBox that shows some initial text at startup.

this is my view: (dont care about the buttons and the listbox for now)

```
<Window x:Class="Friends.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Width="150" Text="{Binding Friend}"></TextBox>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Width="150"></ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Previous" Width="150"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Next" Width="150"></Button>
</Grid>
```

this is my model:

```
public class FriendsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
    public FriendsModel(string _initialName)
    {
        _firstName = _initialName;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string _newName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_newName));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my viewmodel:

```
public class FriendsViewModel
{
    public FriendsModel Friend { get; set; }
    public FriendsViewModel()
    {
        Friend = new FriendsModel("Paul");
    }

}
```

in the code behind i have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new FriendsViewModel();
    }
}
```

my project is building without any errors but it doesnt show the text in my textbox. Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

edit:

i changed it to

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Width="150" Text="{Binding Friend.Firstname}"></TextBox>
```

its still not working.

Comment: You've bound the text box to `Friend` - don't you want `Friend.FirstName` instead? You need to tell the textbox which property to bind to

Comment: can you check the output window? See if any binding error is being displayed?

Comment: @user3292642 did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding should point the FirstName property. WPF can not figure out by him self how to convert Friend class to string.

```
Text="{Binding Friend.FirstName}"
```

Comment: It can do that but than you get Fully qualified name because it is calling the ToString() on the FriendModel

Answer (score 1):

the Friend in the binding represents the full object, you must specify the membre...

try to replace`{Binding Friend}` by `{Binding Friend.FirstName}`

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext is being set right after InitializeComponent() is called, this means that the bindings have already been setup, the textbox is correctly binding to the FirstName property but at the point of binding it's empty.

if you want the textbox to update when the property does you'll need to set DataContext before InitializeComponent()

```
 public MainWindow()
        {    
            DataContext = new FriendsViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();      
        }
```

gives the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
 public FriendsModel(string _initialName)
    {
        this.FirstName = _initialName;
    }
```

Regards,